# Show $S_4$ can't be derived group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, derived-subgroup

> Prove that there is no group $G$ such that $G' = S_4$.

We know that every group of order $24$ is not simple. and $S_4$ is an non-abelian group.

I tried to show that group of order $24$ can not be normal in any group (and because $G'$ is normal in $G, G'$ can not be $S_4$), but I can't prove that group of order $24$ can not be normal.

Comment: Is $S4$ the permutation group? It is not abelian.

Comment: I would say likely so, since it's described as having order $24$

Answer (score 10):

Write $C=C_G(G')$, then $C \cap G'=Z(S_4)=1$. By the N/C theorem $G/C$ injects homomorphically in ${\rm Aut}(S_4)=S_4$. Hence $(G/C)' =G'C/C \cong G'/(G' \cap C) \cong G'$ injects homomorphically in $(S_4)'=A_4$, which is impossible.

Comment: @Shaun (I'm assuming you are pingable here.) In your edit you used `{\rm Aut}` (people also commonly use `\mathrm{Aut}`). It is infact better to use `\operatorname{Aut}`; see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname). (It is not worth re-doing the edit as they render the same here, I just thought you'd be interested.)

Comment: @user1729,  and Shaun - thanks for the edit and remarks guys! Yes I like the \mathrm{} command rather than \text{} or \rm{}.

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning that `\mathrm` is bad! For example, `$\mathrm{Aut}S_4$` gives $\mathrm{Aut}S_4$ while `$\operatorname{Aut}S_4$` gives $\operatorname{Aut}S_4$, which has "correct" spacing. (Or just use brackets...)

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for the clarification. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice generalization, that appeared in a paper entitled *Which groups are commutator subgroups?* in the Liber Amicorum dedicated to Rob van der Waall on the occasion of his retirement.

**Proposition** (René J. Schoof, 2006) Let $n \gt 2$, then $S_n$ never appears as the commutator subgroup of some group.

**Proof** For $n \gt 2$ and $n \neq 6$, the argument of my previous answer works, since in those cases $Z(S_n)=1$ and Aut$(S_n) \cong S_n$. So we only have to deal with $n=6$. It is a famous fact that in that case actually $S_6$ allows for an outer automorphism and if we identify $S_6$ with $\rm{Inn}(S_6)$, then $|\rm{Aut}(S_6):S_6|=2$. Now $A_6 \text{ char } S_6 \lhd \rm{Aut}(S_6)$, so $A_6 \lhd \text{Aut}(S_6)$ and $|\rm{Aut}(S_6):A_6|=4$. This means that $\rm{Aut}(S_6)/A_6$ is abelian, thus $\rm{Aut}(S_6)' \subset A_6$. Now $Z(S_6)=1$, so we can apply again the argument in my other answer and that would imply $S_6 \subset \rm{Aut}(S_6)' \subset A_6$, which is a contradiction. $\square$